# Why isn't my bash array append working?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, append

This script was working just fine on an AIX box, but now on RH linux box the arrays just doesn't seem to work. Version on the new RH box is 4.1.2

I declare my array

```
declare -a gridNames=()
```

I get information about a grid

```
gridstats=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c splunk $host gridStatsTable -m $APPLIANCEMIB -OUQs -Ln`
```

As well as getting the stats from the above, I reuse it to find all the gridNames and then will use the array of gridNames to get stats about their maps.

```
while read -r process; do
        gridNames=(${gridNames[@]} `grep gridName | awk -F "\"" '{print $(NF-1)}'`)
done <<< "$gridstats"
```

The awk part is tested and correctly returns a list of gridnames (just one in this case) but when I echo the array gridNames its empty.

I have also tried using

```
gridNames+=(`grep gridName | awk -F "\"" '{print $(NF-1)}'`)
```

but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `+=` operator for appending elements to an array with **process substitution**:

```
while read -r process; do
    gridNames+=( $(grep 'gridName' | awk -F '"' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$process") )
done < <(snmpwalk -v 2c -c splunk $host gridStatsTable -m $APPLIANCEMIB -OUQs -Ln)
```

Comment: Hmmm yup `while read -r process; do
        gridNames+=( $(grep 'gridName' | awk -F '"' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$process") )
done <<< "$gridstats"` seems to work. I cant pretend for one moment to understand it though :)